# prevent line wrap in terminal buffer

Tags: terminal-buffer, wrapping, job-control

I can easily see the output of a command in a split using vim's terminal

For example, I use `:vertical terminal make re` a lot.

This example is also stated in the help (`h :terminal`):

> Or to run build command:
>
> ```
> :term make myprogram
> ```

I even wrote a short function to easily launch shell commands in a vertical split:

```
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call s:RunShellCommand(<q-args>)
function! s:RunShellCommand(cmdline) abort
    exe 'vert terminal '. a:cmdline
endfunction
```

However, if the output is larger than the terminal width, new lines will be inserted. This makes the output inconsistent (it will depend on the current splits layout, window and screen size, and so on).

[image]

In this state, it's difficult to make use of vim's magic moves, copy, paste, diff, and so on.

Is there any way to get the command output without breaking lines?

I tried using `set nowrap`, `nolinebreak`, `tw=0` with no luck.

Comment: `Is there any way to get the command output without breaking lines?` Right in a Vim terminal buffer, and without a hack or patching Vim, I don't think so.  `If you want to grab the output from a command as it was sent to the terminal, you need to use another way.` ([source](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5769#issuecomment-599023346))

Comment: Oh, if Bram says so. Well, I'm open to ideas for 'another way'.

Comment: @Biggybi *"another way"* Redirect to a file is the obvious one. Use `tee` if you want both to have it display in the terminal and preserve it for reuse inside Vim.

Comment: does it make a difference, if you set $COLUMNS to a smaller value?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt you mean e.g. `set columns=0`? Well, it'll let more space for the output, but the same behavior will apply. @filbranden I've considered `tee` but would like to keep with builtins if possible.

Comment: @Biggybi  no, I mean by setting the environment variable `$COLUMNS` appropriately

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I'm not sure how I could. It seems to be linked to the terminal window width (which would make sense). But a smaller window does not change the problem (it makes it more relevant, actually).

Comment: @Biggybi Yes, that's why set it to the actual terminal window width.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt then I can only say that my terminal does it by itself automatically and does not allow me to change it manually - but it looks consistent with its actual size. However, I struggle to understand how this would be related to my question. I'm trying to display in a terminal *inside* vim, it a split.

Comment: @Biggybi yes, and inside that terminal, tell the shell the explicit usable width, by manually setting the $COLUMNS variable to the actual width of the split window. That's exactly what I would try, because the COLUMNS environment variable is there to tell the shell what useable width is available.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt It still breaks the line at the window width. I can't find a use to it, but if you can test and find something, I'd be glad to hear it. Thanks for being so patient.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution using [channels](https://vimhelp.org/channel.txt.html), an idea based on Bram's presentation in [this video](https://youtu.be/ayc_qpB-93o?t=3137).

```
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call s:TmpShellOutput(<q-args>)
function! s:TmpShellOutput(cmdline) abort
    if bufexists('tmplog')
        " clear buffer content
        call deletebufline('tmplog', 1, '$')
    else
        " create new buffer that will not be listed
        call bufadd('tmplog')
        call setbufvar('tmplog', "buftype", "nofile")
        call setbufvar('tmplog', "filetype", "nofile")
    endif
    " start a job with bash on the argument
    let logjob = job_start(["/bin/bash", "-c", a:cmdline],
                \ {'out_io': 'buffer', 'out_name': 'tmplog', 'out_msg': ''})
    " show the buffer as a panel on the far right-hand side, unwrapped
    vert sbuffer tmplog
    wincmd L
    30 wincmd |
endfunction
```

Use the command like in this example :

```
:Shell make re
```

This function will use a buffer `tmplog` to output the result of a job. The buffer is cleared at each call, allowing successive uses without pilling up the buffer list.

Several caveats:

- Ansi escape codes are printed as is, breaking colors and cluttering the output
- Very long commands can struggle sometimes. I don't know exactly in which circumstance, but computing power seems to be a factor
- `<c-c>` does not stop the job... `:bw` does when it does not hang vim

I could theoretically add a local mapping from the function:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <c-c> :call job_stop('logjob')<cr>
```

But is just hangs Vim. Maybe my laptop was to hot by the time I tested that.