# why is the terminal output resized, after the command is executed, when moving it from a function

Tags: terminal-buffer, line-breaks

### The problem

I'm trying to write a function that outputs a shell command in a terminal vertical split.

Vim's terminal, as any terminal, will break lines that are wider than the terminal window.
As there's [no working around this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25060/prevent-line-wrap-in-terminal-buffer), I still would like to get the widest possible output (that is, the screen width).

After executing for example `:terminal cat wide_file`, moving the window to the right manually with `ctrl-w_L` does not change the break point.

I can't reproduce this behaviour from a function: the lines are broken to the new window width, even if moving the window *after* the shell command is executed in a wider window.

### What I have

```
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call s:RunShellCommand(<q-args>)
function! s:RunShellCommand(cmdline) abort
    " wipe previous command output
    if bufexists('scratch_terminal_output')
        bw! scratch_terminal_output
    endif
    " execute the command in a wide window
    wincmd v
    wincmd J
    let current_window = win_getid()
    if has("nvim")
        exe 'terminal '. a:cmdline
    else
        exe 'terminal ++curwin'. a:cmdline
    endif
    file scratch_terminal_output
    let term_window = win_getid()
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    " moving the window to the right, assigning a new width
    wincmd L
    60 wincmd|
    " back to where we were before executing
    if win_getid() != current_window
        call win_gotoid(current_window)
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    endif
endfunction
```

### What I tried so far

In this part, the "xxxxxx" section, which does not work as expected, is removed.

#### Using another function called at the end of the above

```
function! MoveTermToRight(term_window, current_window) abort
    call win_gotoid(term_window)
    wincmd L
    60 wincmd|
    call win_gotoid(current_window)
endfunction
```

#### Using another function and running it in the command

```
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call s:RunShellCommand(<q-args>) | call MoveLastWindowToRight()
function! MoveLastWindowToRight()
    wincmd p
    wincmd L
    60 wincmd|
    wincmd p
endfunction
```

#### Using an autocommand to move the window after leaving the buffer

```
au BufLeave scratch_terminal_output wincmd L | 60 wincmd |
```

#### Using a mapping

(Well, I've been experimenting.)

```
nnoremap \ls :Shell ls <cr><bar>:wincmd p<cr><bar>:wincmd L<cr><bar>:wincmd p<cr>
```

Vim breaks each line at the new width, whatever approach I tried.

### Why not stick with the [channels approach](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25060/prevent-line-wrap-in-terminal-buffer)?

It's sluggish, especially when displaying large outputs (e.i. ~100MB file).

### Edit

I guess [dedowsdi](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25528/why-is-the-terminal-output-resized-after-the-command-is-executed-when-moving-i?noredirect=1#comment44952_25528) gave the answer.
Any workaround welcome.

Comment: My guessing is `term ...` is async, it's actually executed after all `wincmd ` (which change terminal width).

Comment: Well indeed, that's even the whole point... I feel silly...

Comment: Perhaps polling `term_getstatus()` and checking when it's finished? Though I think you're probably better off running the command using `:!` or `systemlist()` and using a scratch buffer to display the output... The `:terminal` is great if you want the user to interact with the terminal, but just showing command output, maybe not the best option.

Comment: @filbranden I'll have a look at `term_getstatus()`, it sounds promising, thanks. Also, I indeed would like it to be interactive :) I'll check that tomorrow.